# How to acces variable of a Movie Clip through getChildAt() method. Doing it by just typing instance name works properly

Tags: actionscript-3

I have for loop and I need to target all variables inside movie clips by getChildAt() method. These variables are not in a classes, but in a regular timeline script inside it. If I type instance name of an object everything seems to work properly but it's soo loong. I cannot typecast coz it's not a class. Typecasting it as Object or MovieClip gives an error:

Property clicked not found on flash.display.Shape and there is no default value. as Object and

TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.display::Shape@35dcf139 to flash.display.MovieClip. as MovieClip....................................

by the way.. this is my code that is inside parent mc:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checking)

function checking(e:Event)
{
for(var i = 0; i< numChildren; i++)
{
    if(MovieClip(getChildAt(i)).clicked == true)
    {
        clickedCardsNum += 1;

        trace(clickedCardsNum);
    }
}
}
```

this gives an error

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checking)

function checking(e:Event)
{
for(var i = 0; i< numChildren; i++)
{
      if(myCard1.clicked == true)
    {
        clickedCardsNum += 1;

        trace(clickedCardsNum);
    }
}
}
```

and this one works correctly

The only working solution for that may be put all of that code inside classes an then typecast my getChildAt method by that class name. I want to know if it's a simpler method of acces it. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try it :

```
var d:DisplayObject;
for( var i:int = 0; i < numChildren; ++i )
{
    d = getChildAt(i);
    if( d.hasOwnProperty('clicked') && d['clicked'] == true)
    {
        clickedCardsNum += 1;
        trace(clickedCardsNum);
    }
}
```

Because with getChildAt method you get all displayObjects not only MovieClip and MovieClip don't have clicked propertie, i think it's just your card items having it.

The function hasOwnProperty check if property exists and then you can access the property by its name with ['propName'] and it won't make compiler errors.

Maybe keeping an array of your cards item would be a better way of doing it ;)

I hope this could help you

Comment: Oh maan! Thank you so much! It works very well and you helped me very much! I didn't know what "hasOwnProperty" can be useful for. Now I know! Thanks again!